# Missing snapshot folder in Iphone Simulator

Tags: ios, caching

I want to remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background.

I'm following what apple recommends:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1838/_index.html

I'm not able to verify that this solution is working because in the simulator I can't find the folder where the snapshots are saved:

> /Library/Caches/Snapshots/$(BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)/